# Convert a code from FORTRAN to C

Tags: c++, c, fortran

I have the following FORTRAN code which I need to convert to C or C++. I already tried using f2c, but it didn't work out. It has something to do with conversion from Lambert Conformal wind vector to a True-North oriented vector.
Is anyone experienced in FORTRAN who could possibly help?

```
PARAMETER ( ROTCON_P   =  0.422618      )
PARAMETER ( LON_XX_P   = -95.0          )
PARAMETER ( LAT_TAN_P  =  25.0          )

    do j=1,ny_p
    do i=1,nx_p
       angle2 = rotcon_p*(olon(i,j)-lon_xx_p)*0.017453
       sinx2 = sin(angle2)
       cosx2 = cos(angle2)
     do k=1,nzp_p
       ut = u(i,j,k)
       vt = v(i,j,k)   
       un(i,j,k) = cosx2*ut+sinx2*vt
       vn(i,j,k) =-sinx2*ut+cosx2*vt
      end if
     end do
    end do
```

Thanks a lot for any help or tip.

Comment: Are you sure you've copied the code accurately? You have an `end if`, but no `if` for it to match up with (and a `do` with no matching `end do`). Is there a chance the `end if` is really an `end do`?

Comment: Do you want c or c++? You write c in the title, but have tagged the question with both.

Comment: Define "didn't work out". Did you get compile errors? Linker errors? Runtime errors? Did f2c spit out an error message? Like Jerry asks, are you sure you copied the code correctly? The translation should be reasonably straightforward; the only hitches would be making sure the variables are the right type and declared at the right scope.

Comment: @John: I can guess at that. Trying to use the output of f2c in anyway except feeding it right into a compiler is pure folly: it is simply not meant for human consumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I speak Fortran as well as Tarzan speaks English, but this should be the gist of it in C:

```
#include <math.h>

const double ROTCON_P = 0.422618;
const double LON_XX_P = -95.0;
const double LAT_TAN_P = 25.0;

int i, j, k;
double angle2, sinx2, cosx2, ut, vt;
double un[nzp_p][ny_p][nx_p];
double vn[nzp_p][ny_p][nx_p];

for (j=0; j<ny_p; ++j) {
    for (i=0; i<nx_p; ++i) {
        angle2 = ROTCON_P * (olon[j][i] - LON_XX_P) * 0.017453;
        sinx2 = sin(angle2);
        cosx2 = cos(angle2);
        for (k=0; k<nzp_p; ++k) {
            ut = u[k][j][i];
            vt = v[k][j][i];
            un[k][j][i] = (cosx2 * ut) + (sinx2 * vt);
            vn[k][j][i] = (-1 * sinx2 * ut) + (cosx2 * vt);
        }
    }
}
```

You will need to declare `olon`, `u`, `v`, `nx_p`, `ny_p`, and `nzp_p` somewhere and assign them a value before running this code.  There is not enough context info given for me to know exactly what they are.

Answer (score 2):

This will get you started - I didn't try to compile it, but it's close to what you're going to need.  I assumed that the arrays olon, u, v, un, and vn are passed in to your function as pointers.

```
const double rotcon_p   =  0.422618;
const double lon_xx_p   = -95.0;
const double lat_tan_p  =  25.0;

for (j=0;j<ny_p;++j)
{
  for (i=0,i<nx_p;++i)
  {
    double angle2 = rotcon_p*(olon[i][j]-lon_xx_p)*0.017453;
    double sinx2 = sin(angle2);
    double cosx2 = cos(angle2);
    for (k=0;k<nsp_p;++k)
    {
      double ut = u[i][j][k]
      double vt = v[i][j][k]
      un[i][j][k] = cosx2*ut+sinx2*vt
      vn[i][j][k] =-sinx2*ut+cosx2*vt
   }
  }
}
```

If you're staying completely in c/c++ this will be fine, if you're mixing FORTRAN and c/c++, you need to know that FORTRAN and c/c++ index their arrays backwards, so you may have to swap your indices to make it work

```
const double rotcon_p   =  0.422618;
const double lon_xx_p   = -95.0;
const double lat_tan_p  =  25.0;

for (j=0;j<ny_p;++j)
{
  for (i=0,i<nx_p;++i)
  {
    double angle2 = rotcon_p*(olon[j][i]-lon_xx_p)*0.017453;
    double sinx2 = sin(angle2);
    double cosx2 = cos(angle2);
    for (k=0;k<nsp_p;++k)
    {
      double ut = u[k][j][i]
      double vt = v[k][j][i]
      un[k][j][i] = cosx2*ut+sinx2*vt
      vn[k][j][i] =-sinx2*ut+cosx2*vt
   }
  }
}
```

But I don't have enough context for your problem to tell you which you need to do.

Comment: It's also worth noting that his arrays use 1 and n for the start-index and end-index, respectively, instead of 0 and n-1. This is not unusual in FORTRAN, of course.

Comment: yes, that's why I changed the for loops so that the data being referenced would be the same.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fragment of code, which may be why f2c didn't work.  Plus, as already pointed out, most likely the "end if" should be "end do".

If you have Fortran subroutines that are tested and do the calculation that you need, you can call them from C.  You declare the arguments of the Fortran subroutine using the ISO C Binding of Fortran, then the Fortran compiler will use the C API so that the routine is callable from C.   This short code block is easy to translate; something long and complicated might be better to reuse.